# React native Expo FileSystem.readAsStringAsync convert result to base64

Tags: file, react-native, base64, encode, expo

I’m using Expo's [DocumentPicker](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v30.0.0/sdk/document-picker) to get a file on my device, this gives me a uri that i’m passing to `FileSystem.readAsStringAsync` which returns some unreadable binary string. I would like to convert this to base64 format but I don't know how.
I've tried using the [base-64](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base-64) library's `encode` function but this gives me a way too long base64 that doesn't translate into a file.

```
import base64 from 'base-64';
import utf8 from 'utf8';
//
const response: IDocumentPickerResponse = await Expo.DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({
    base64: true,
    copyToCacheDirectory: false,
    type: '*/*',
});
const file: string = await Expo.FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(response.uri);
const bytes: string = utf8.encode(file);
const encoded: string = base64.encode(bytes);
```

It seemed to me that `readAsStringAsync` was based on [rn-fetch-blob](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/wiki/File-System-Access-API#readfilepath-encodingpromise) where you could pass an `encoding` param (base64) to the `readFile` function but it is not the case with the `FileSystem` API...

EDIT: MORE TESTS

Using `utf8` and `base-64` libs, i’ve compared the base64 encoded result with the actual valid base64 string of a plain white image to identify where the problem appeared. Here’s the **valid** uncompressed base64 string:

> Qk12EwAAAAAAADYAAAAoAAAASgAAABYAAAABABgAAAAAAEATAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////AAD///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////8AAP///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////wAA////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////AAD///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////8AAP///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////wAA////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////AAD///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////8AAP///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////wAA////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////AAD///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////8AAP///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////wAA////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////AAD///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////8AAP///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////wAA////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////AAD///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////8AAP///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////wAA////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////AAD///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////8AAP///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////wAA////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////AAA=

and here’s the **unvalid** one:

> 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

We can see that the first characters of both strings are identical:

> Qk12EwAAAAAAADYAAAAoAAAASgAAABYAAAABABgAAAAAAEATAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

and that the second base64 gets unvalid when it meets a “/” char. We can also notice some redundant patterns in the unvalid base64 eventhough the valid one contains mainly slashes. Moreover, the unvalid one is twice as long as the valid one.

I have no idea what this means but my guess is that `readAsStringAsync` makes some strange encoding somewhere in the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably know by now that the following will do it (supported in expo sdk 31):

```
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';

const base64Img = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(uri, { encoding: FileSystem?.EncodingType?.Base64 });

<ImageBackground  source={uri: `data:image/jpeg;base64,${base64Img}`} />
```

Comment: BTW, did anyone try to write the base64 string to firestore? I am writing it as a base64 string using ref.putString(base64String, 'base64', { contentType: 'image/jpeg' }), but when I try to view it, I cannot see the image.

Comment: @clementino36 take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53294492/reading-a-file-from-expos-cache-as-base64-writing-to-firestore. Perhaps you can help...