# Reading a file from Expo's cache as base64, writing to firebase storage (Cloud Storage for Firebase)

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-storage, expo

After using expo's ImagePicker and saving the image in the local cache, I am trying to save the image to firebase storage (or its new name, Cloud Storage for Firebase).

The relevant code is:

```
base64String =
  FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(photoUri,
  { encoding: FileSystem.EncodingTypes.Base64 });
```

and then

```
ref.putString(base64String,'base64',
  { contentType: 'image/jpeg' })
```

However, something is wrong with the image that I save to firestore, and I cannot view it (either directly from the firestore console or my code).

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: I never used firebase but did you take a look at this? https://github.com/expo/firebase-storage-upload-example

Comment: Yes... I have other problems with this code, that's why I am trying to use readAsStringAsync. See: https://github.com/expo/firebase-storage-upload-example/issues/14

Comment: Have you found any solution for this issue? I'm facing exact same problem.

Comment: No, I haven't...

Answer (score 0):

the problem here is the upload funcition that uses the standard atob and btob functions. that are missing in react-native/expo while expo uses the web js implementation which thinks it's running on the browser.

solution works from here:
[React Native atob() / btoa() not working without remote JS debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42829838/react-native-atob-btoa-not-working-without-remote-js-debugging)

this will add global btoa, atob funcitions
add it to App.js and there you go..

```
import {decode, encode} from 'base-64'

if (!global.btoa) {
    global.btoa = encode;
}

if (!global.atob) {
    global.atob = decode;
}
```