# Advice on RN Camera w/ Firebase & Image Orientation?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, exif

Im dying here ;) My RN/Expo app takes photos and stores them on Firebase. ... that part works fine.

However, it seems that on iOS RN/Expo Camera writes some exif orientation data that is never truly reliable. It sometimes changes the orientation to rotated 90 CCW sometimes not. Boo.

I need some advice on the best pattern for this. Is the best idea to force Exif BEFORE upload or read the exif data and orient the image on the client side? My gut is the latter.

I stupidly assumed this was trivial but it seems it isn't. Can anyone point me in the right direction on this?

Also, I need to understand how to read exif data in RN. The only npm I found requires the image to be local vs. using a uri.

Comment: Would a library like [react-exif-orientation-img](https://github.com/rricard/react-exif-orientation-img) which compensates for the ignored exif data by producing CSS transforms be suitable?

Comment: Its for react .... not react native :(

Comment: My fault for not reading your question correctly, apologies!

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but perhaps you can help me.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53294492/reading-a-file-from-expos-cache-as-base64-writing-to-firebase-storage-cloud-s

Comment: Sorry @Yossi ... didnt use base64